# Objects getting skipped when listening to a Stream through Streambuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to listen to a stream provided by the Directory. [Flutter Directory Doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html).

The problem is if there are like 9 Directories it only print's the last directory skipping the rest, also I'm very new to these concepts I can't debug it myself.

When I try to print the commented listener in the initState it prints every directory.

```
class _MediaFilesState extends State<MediaFiles> {
  Directory internalStorage = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/');

  WatchlistDatabase watchlistDatabase = WatchlistDatabase();

  StreamController<FileSystemEntity> _streamController =
      StreamController<FileSystemEntity>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    checkMediaPath();

    _streamController
        .addStream(internalStorage.list(recursive: false, followLinks: false));

    // _streamController.stream.listen((FileSystemEntity entity) {
    //   if (entity is File) {
    //     print(entity.path);
    //   } else {
    //     print(entity.path);
    //   }
    // });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _streamController.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF131214),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: mediaFilesWidget,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 400,
            width: 250,
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _streamController.stream,
              initialData: 23,
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print(snapshot.data.path);
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scan` method/transformer from https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/scan.html to collect the values from the previous events into an array of values.